# How to get UWP title bar default colors programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp

How to get UWP title bar color programmatically?

I can easy set custom title bar colors with:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.BackgroundColor
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.ForegroundColor
```

But how to get system title bar colors?
E.g. If user set *Show color on title bar* option and use *Yellow* as Windows Accent Color then UWP App title bar `BackgroundColor` is *Yellow*.
But `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.BackgroundColor` return *null*.

[Screenshot of win 10 color setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj6aI.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's AccentColor.
You can get it programmatically

```
var color = new UISettings().GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);
```

or try

```
var color = (Color)Resources["SystemAccentColor"];
```

Comment: It does not enough. 
We have to know 'Show color on title bar' setting is ON to use AccentColor or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can set `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;` and make custom ttitle bar

Comment: Correct. This is exactly my target - to create custom title bar which is very similar to original but with some additions (e.g. add button). I need to get original title color and use it at my custom title bar. And I can't find how to achieve it since I do not know user's  'Show color on title bar' setting value. As workaround I use default white color for title and system buttons but it does not match with user desired color if 'Show color on title bar' is set (and title blinks on splash)

Comment: I think you don't have to be too strict. Just use accent color.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer the question :( 

In our office only one person who set this setting ON (default is OFF) so we have sacrificed his (and other people who set this option ON) wish to see an ancient color in title bar and use default colors for all users (until find the way to 100% know the color of title bar).

Comment: Hey @Yury , did you ever figure out the answer to this question? As far as I can tell, there is no API to determine if the user has enabled "Show color on title bar". I am adding a manual option so the user can pick between the application title bar color and the system accent color if they really want to.